# how to store files into sqlite

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, sqlite

I m creating document files using filemanager which is text file.i want to store this files into sqlite tables?How can i store from iphone and what data types can be used?
Thank u..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your app is linked to a sqlite library, just create a database and then add tables and data. I'm not really clear where you're getting hung up.

Comment: as u told that is to store simple data,i want store whole document file (like attachment of file to email) in to database table..is it posible in sqlite database??

Comment: You're being very vague. Are you writing software or what? And, if so, with what. If you want to store an entire document, just copy the document. I don't see where you'd need sqlite for that. If for some odd reason, you want to copy a file using sqlite, you can use the back-up functions starting with sqlite3_backup_init().

Comment: then what would be the best solution for this,either i can store only content of file and file name in the table or whole file?? give me proper guide line or any source code

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xcode so I can't provide source code. Do you just want to know how to copy any file?